# Entity Framework composite key delete with one primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

Here's some of my database design on my assignments

```
Customer
--------
CustomerID (PK)

Cake
-------
CakeID (PK)

Cart
-------
CustomerID (PK, FK)
CakeID (PK, FK)
```

I'd like to make a function `clearUserCart(User user)` in my Cart Repository class but I have no idea how to make function to delete all rows with specified user.

**EDIT :**
I have figured out how to do it, just use `getCartOfUser(User user)` which returns `List<Cart>`. Then do foreach loop to remove.
In SQL, it could be achieved just by one line `DELETE FROM Cart WHERE CustomerID = <the cust id>`, is there an equivalent one line statement in entity framework?

Comment: I think reading [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2802240/crud-using-entity-framework-in-.net-framework-5.0---delete) will help you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF 6, you can use the RemoveRange method.

So it could look something like this;

```
context.Cart.RemoveRange(cartItem => cartItem.CustomerID == CustomerToDelete);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use `context.Carts.RemoveRange(queryable.Where(c => c.CustomerID == <the cust id>)).`

2) You can add reference to  [Entity Framework Extended Library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) and use like this syntax `context.Carts.Where(c => c.CustomerID == <the cust id>).Delete()`